# Ignore hyphen when searching with django-haystack

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

I'm trying to do some searching with `haystack` with the `whoosh` backend.

In my document i have string `1234-567`

and my search could look like this

`SearchQuerySet().filter(content="1234567`)

Haystack does not find the object because of the hyphen between `1234` and `567`.

Anyone know how i should solve this?
Should i remove the hyphen when generating the document?
Also other characters like "." and "/" could cause the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to do it when generating the document. This can be done by defining a preparation method: http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation

So maybe for your case, something like:

```
content = indexes.CharField()

def prepare_content(self, obj):
    return ''.join(obj.content.split('-'))
```

If it's more than just a single char, you might wanna use regular expressions to clean up the string.